# ProGuard - org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type

Tags: android, proguard, restlet

I have an Android-based application which is connecting to the Google App Engine using Rest services, the app works perfectly until it is obfuscated through ProGuard prior to release.

The error reported in LogCat when running the obfuscated app is:

```
Unable to convert a [application/json,UTF-8] representation into an object of 
  class com.enterprisemk.android.bcw.bincollection.WasteCollectionAreasContainer

org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found 
  for type [simple type, class 
  com.enterprisemk.android.bcw.bincollection.WasteCollectionAreasContainer]: 
  can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
```

I have the following in my proguard-project.txt file:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

-keep public class org.w3c.** {public private protected *;}
-dontwarn org.w3c.**

-keep public class org.joda.time.** {public private protected *;}
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**

-keep public class org.restlet.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.restlet.**

-keep public class org.codehaus.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.codehaus.**

-keepattributes Signature
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
```

And my class the error refers to looks like:

```
public class WasteCollectionAreasContainer {

 public List<WasteCollectionAreas> wasteCollectionAreasList;

 public List<WasteCollectionAreas> getWasteCollectionAreasList() {
     return wasteCollectionAreasList;
 }

 public void setWasteCollectionAreasist(List<WasteCollectionAreas> wasteCollectionAreasList) {
     this.wasteCollectionAreasList = wasteCollectionAreasList;
 }

 public WasteCollectionAreasContainer() {
     wasteCollectionAreasList = new ArrayList<WasteCollectionAreas>();
 }

 @JsonCreator
 public WasteCollectionAreasContainer(List<WasteCollectionAreas> wasteCollectionAreasList) {
     this.wasteCollectionAreasList = wasteCollectionAreasList;
 }
}
```

To reiterate prior to obfuscation through ProGuard the app works perfectly.
Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: some time progaurd removes some classes from build path specially library projects.

Comment: Sounds like Proguard may have removed the default, non-parameterized constructor for `WasteCollectionAreasContainer`. Does that class have an overloaded constructor too? It could be Proguard is stripping the default constructor *because* there is an overload *and* it thinks the default constructor is not being used anywhere - that may happen because Proguard can't detect that Jackson actually uses/requires a default constructors for POJOs at runtime.

Comment: MH - this set me off in the right direction to fixing the issue - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type
    [simple type, class com.enterprisemk.android.bcw.bincollection.WasteCollectionAreasContainer]:
    can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
```

suggests that the Jackson library is trying to deserialize your class using reflection, with its original name and its annotated constructor. ProGuard can't foresee this, so it may have removed or renamed the class and its constructor. You probably need to preserve them explicitly:

```
-keep class com.enterprisemk.android.bcw.bincollection.WasteCollectionAreasContainer {
    <init>(java.util.List);
}
```

There may be other similar classes/fields/methods that need to be preserved for the same reasons.

Comment: Eric - essentially, this is what I did. And you were right, I had other classes/fields/methods that needed preserving similarly.  Thanks for the bang-on response.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your `Proguard.config`. It will help you locate the issue.

```
-verbose 
-dump class_files.txt 
-printseeds seeds.txt 
-printusage unused.txt 
-printmapping mapping.txt
```

> I have the following in my proguard-project.txt file

I believe you should be using `proguard-android-optimize.txt`, and not `proguard-android.txt`.

For completeness, thank Riley Hassell on [Android Security Discussions](http://groups.google.com/group/android-security-discuss/browse_thread/thread/f17e503bf1b969c6/6f9f3819f0f933f2) for the tricks.

Comment: The standard Ant/Eclipse builds already contain the -print options; you should find the resulting files in the directory bin/proguard. ProGuard's optimization step processes the code some more; it generally doesn't solve any configuration problems. Still, it's recommended for best results.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution, in case anyone else has this problem, is the following:

```
# keep anything annotated with @JsonCreator
-keepclassmembers public class * {
     @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator *;
}
```

That keeps any method annotated with JsonCreator, which is probably wanted to do in this case. If you have multiple classes needing to be loaded, then you can avoid having to specify each class individually.